# Unable to find TestNG in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng, ubuntu-16.04

I have an `Ubuntu Studio 16.10`.  I have an  `IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2`
Build #IC-163.10154.41, built on December 21, 2016

```
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 amd64
```

`JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit` Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
I use  `Apache Maven 3.3.9`
I have used the following in my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
     <project.build.sourceencoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceencoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

     <build>
         <plugins>
         <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

      <version>3.1</version>
      <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
     </plugin>

     </plugins>


 </build>


</project>
```

I went to my project directory and ran `mvn clean install`
I also checked another post, wherein it was advised to right clicking on the project folder and selecting Maven-> reimport, but that option was not available.
I got a `BUILD Success`. Although the external library showed presence of junit.  I never saw TestNG.  In the logs it said.. downloading `testng-6.9.12.jar`
When I used `locate testng-6.9.12.jar` all I got is a return to the command prompt.
In the editor, I tried to import org.testng.*; The import statement got erased as soon as I finished writing it.  I use a vim kinda arrangement on `Intellij` `Ubuntu 16.10`
I have also tried downloading from jcentral and maven repositiories but to  no avail.

I cannot see TestNG in external libraries only `junit` and `Java 1.8`

Comment: Did you try to reimport the project as a maven one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably because Maven could not find `6.9.12` in the Maven central (Since your pom file does not have any `<repository>` tag, maven will go try looking for your artifact only in `repo1.maven.org/maven2/`).

I tried searching for it [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/) and could not find a version 6.9.12

The latest released version of TestNG is `6.10`. So please replace your `<version>` tag in your `<dependency>` to `6.10` and try again. That should take care of it.

`<scope>test</scope>` is merely a convenient way of telling Maven, that you need TestNG to be resolved only when you are running your tests. The default scope of `compile` tells TestNG that an artifact is to be made available when compiling the code itself (typically `src/main/java`). It doesn't have anything to do with the issue that you are facing here (Atleast as far as I know)

Comment: I have mentioned a repository

Comment: Can you please open up a command prompt, run the command "mvn dependency:tree | grep testng" and check what you see ? If you see testng, then it basically means that your project has no issues, but maybe your IntelliJ has gotten corrupted.To fix this, you can try removing the ".idea" folder from your root folder of your project and then re-import the project back into IntelliJ

Comment: I did not see testng

Comment: In that case, I am guessing that something is wrong with your ~/.m2 folder (Here "~" refers to your home directory). So I would suggest that you please delete ~/.m2 folder, open up a command prompt, navigate to the directory that contains your pom.xml, run "mvn dependency:resolve" and then try running "mvn dependency:tree | grep testng" (from the same directory that contains your pom.xml). that should take care.

Comment: I got [INFO] +- org.testng:testng:jar:6.10:compile.  However when I opened intellij i did not see TestNG in the external libraries.  Is there anything else I need to do

Comment: Did you try deleting ".idea" folder and all the *.iml files in your project directory (make sure you close IntelliJ when doing this), and then re-importing the project again into IntelliJ ?

Comment: Sorry for the late thank you, but it's a big thank you.  It worked.

Comment: I clicked on the upvote, but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."  Is there anything I can do?